# Swift handle lots of complex operations

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm working on a Swift project with complicated notification calculations. I'm looping through an array of objects which I need to do a very complex operation to determine when to schedule notifications. Currently I am doing:

```
for item in items {
    //some logic here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        //complex operation here, then schedule notification
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is proving to be slow since I am doing this for a bunch of objects that are all trying to use the same queue. Sometimes it doesn't finish scheduling the notifications before the user leaves the app. What are my options to improve the performance? I was thinking instead of having everything use the global high priority queue I could create new queues each time somehow so they are not waiting on each other?

Comment: Have you profiled your app to find out what the bottleneck actually is?

Comment: Yes the notification fire date calculation is highly intensive... we are using a 3rd party solution that unfortunately we have no control of.

Comment: Without seeing your logic in performing the calculations I can't say much but you might want to try performing certain calculations earlier when the user is using your app so that when you want to schedule the notifications there are less work to be done. Showing your logic in your codes instead of two lines of comment might help.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, I don't think you need to use the "main thread" for calculation, the main thread is mainly for UI updates. You should use background thread to handle those heavy operations and schedule notifications. Otherwise you app is going to be very laggy and not responsive(as you main thread is occupied by those operations)
2. Second, in stead of firing multiple main thread operations using a for loop. You should put the code in this way.

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
      for item in items {
         //some logic here
         //complex operation here, then schedule notification
      }

   }
   ```

   As you didnt provide code of the complex operation, can't give any advise on that part. Feel free to add follow up questions. :D